# Can't get Facebook Login to work on Meteor

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor, meteor-accounts

I cannot get Meteor.loginWithFacebook to work, I have looked at so many Q&A's here, and they all do it differently but none works for me. (It has only worked with accounts-ui, but I need my custom login page)

I have installed accounts-password, accounts-facebook and service-configuration

Server Code (Not Real ClientId or Secret):

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert({
    service: "facebook"
}, {
    $set: {
        clientId: "2234324234324",
        loginStyle: "redirect",
        secret: "324234234234324234234"
    }
});
```

Client Code (on click button, using ui-router controller as variable "vm"):

```
vm.facebook = function() {
    Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
            requestPermissions: ['email']
        },
        function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log("There was an error : " + err);
            } else {
                console.log('No Error!');
            }
        });
};
```

Comment: At your facebook app dashboard. Does your app have the circle on green and says "This app is public and available to all users" ?

Comment: Yeah I do have the green button! I made it public several days ago.

Comment: Is this similar to yours? http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/41741539120/building-a-customized-accounts-ui-for-meteor